# SearchResultsController obscures screen when used with UINavigationItem

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, viewcontroller, uisearchcontroller, navigationcontroller

I'm using new integrated `UISearchBar` available in iOS 11, the problem is as soon as I tap on the searchbar and start typing text, the `SearchResultsController` obscures the whole screen, including the searchbar. It is impossible to dismiss the results controller or cancel search afterwards.

To demonstrate the issue, I've configured a minimal reproducible example:

```
import UIKit

let reuseid = "reuseIdentifier"
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseid)
  }

  // MARK: - Table view data source

  override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseid, for: indexPath)
    return cell
  }

  func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    print(searchController.searchBar.text)
  }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var searchController: UISearchController!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: TableViewController())
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
  }
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
    window?.rootViewController = nc
    return true
  }
}
```

1. Initial state
   [image: 1]
2. Tapping on the SearchBar
   [image: 2]
3. The screen is obscured by the `UITableView` - colored in green
   [image: 3]

**What could cause this bug and how can it be avoided?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding this to the `SearchResultsUpdater`:

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

With default edges, the `ResultsController` tries to extend its view beyond the `UINavigationBar` and hence, obscures it:

[image]